# Sharepoint Workflow "Replace item level permission" action

Tags: workflow

SP workflow : "Replace item level permission" action
I would like to ask whether this action will replace all the original permission.
If yes , how to add back the original and the new permission on the selection menu.

Comment: what is this selection menu?

Comment: I mean user selection UI menu